# Count the number of permutations of $\{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4\}$ in which every two consecutive numbers are different

Tags: combinatorics

Count the number of permutations of $\{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4\}$ in which every two
consecutive numbers are different.

My attempt:I think it should be $$8!-\frac{8P2}{2!}\times \frac{8P2}{2!}\times \frac{8P2}{2!}=40320-21952=18368$$.Is this correct?or I am stupid?

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more, think inclusion/exclusion.

$8!$ is the total number. Then consider the set $A_i$, the set of all permutations where the two $i's$ are adjacent, where $i=1,2,3,4$.

How to count $A_i$: consider the two $i$'s as one element $I$ and permute the other 6 elements and $I$, and this can be done in $7!$ ways. So there are $7!$ many elements in $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$, so we'd get $8! - 4\cdot 7!$.

But! We double count here, as both $i$ and $j$ for different $i$ and $j$ could be together and we'd count the same permuation in both $A_i$ and $A_j$, and we substract it twice.

So we have to add all the double ones again: $A_i \cap A_j$ where $1 \le i < j \le 4$.

There are ${4 \choose 2}$ many such pairs, and counting them in the same way (identify the two $i$'s to $I$, the two $j$'s to $J$ and permuting the 6 elements), all of them have $6!$ elements. So we get $8! - 4\cdot 7! + {4 \choose 2}6!$ many.

But we double count again... etc.

Comment: So total number of permutations are $$8!-4.7!+4C2 \times 6!-4C3\times 5!-4!=24024$$

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: Yep, I think so.